# Percolation and number of phases in the 2D Ising model

Tags: mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics, probability, ising-model, percolation

**Update.** As my previous figure had conceptual mistakes I decided to change the picture to another, more instructive.

After a long time I came back to try to understand an article on the Ising model.
The review article is [Percolation and number of phases in the 2D Ising
model](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907186) by Hans-Otto Georgii and Yasunari Higuchi (published in 2000 in the **Journal of Mathematical Physics** as *Percolation and number of phases in the two-dimensional Ising model*).

I confess that since after the first half of the statement of the first theme got lost. For an expert my doubts about the second half of the proof of the lemma below is certainly primitive.

I reproduce below the statement of the lemma and its proof together as some figures to illustrate what I did the first half of the demonstration of the lemma.

> ***Lema 2.1(Existence of infinite clusters)**
> If $\mu\in\mathcal{G}$ is different from $\mu^-$, there exists with
> positive probability an infinite $+$cluster.
> That is, $\mu(E^+)>0$ when $\mu\ne\mu^-$.*

[Here, $\mathcal{G}$ is the set of Gibbs measures of the Ising model of first neighbors in the net $\mathbb{Z}^2$. And $\mu^-$ is the extremal Gibbs measure, which is obtained by
thermodynamic limit of finite volume measures whit borders fixed in negative sign.
$E^+$ denotes the event que there exists an infinite cluster of spins in state $+$.]

***Proof.**
Suppose that $\mu(E^+)=0$. Then any given square
$\Delta$ is almost surely surrounded by a $-*$circuit, and with
probability close to $1$ such a circuit can already be found within a
square $\Lambda\supset\Delta$ provided $\Lambda$ is large enough. If this
occurs, we let $\Gamma$ be
the largest random subset of $\Lambda$ which is the
interior of such a $-*$circuit. (A largest such set exists because
the union of such sets is again the interior of a $-*$circuit.)
In the alternative case we set $\Gamma=\emptyset$. By
maximality, $\Gamma$ is determined from outside [ see figure below].*

[image]

So far I understand the argument. And in any section of this theorem repeats this argument in several demonstrations. But what comes next does not seem intelligible to a non specialist. I have no idea how the properties below to get the desired equality through the instruction below:

***Continuation of proof:** The **strong Markov
property** together with the **stochastic monotonicity**
$\mu^-_\Gamma\preceq \mu^-$ therefore implies (in the limit $\Lambda\uparrow\mathbb{Z}^2$)
that $\mu\preceq\mu^-$ on $\mathcal{F}_\Delta$.
Since $\Delta$ was arbitrary and $\mu^-$ is minimal we find that
$\mu=\mu^-$, and the lemma is proved.* $\Box$

**Question:** How to use the **strong Markov property** and the **stochastic monotonicity** to finish the proof of lemma? Below the properties used as set out in Article.

> $\bullet$
> the **strong Markov property** of Gibbs measures,
> stating that
> $\mu(\cdot\,|\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma^c})(\omega) =\mu_{\Gamma(\omega)}^\omega$ for
> $\mu$-almost
> all $\omega$ when $\Gamma$ is
> any finite random subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ which is  determined from
> outside, in that
> $\{\Gamma=\Lambda\}\in\mathcal{F}_{\Lambda^c}$ for all finite $\Lambda$, and
> $\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma^c}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of all events $A$ outside
> $\Gamma$, in the sense that
> $A\cap \{\Gamma=\Lambda\}\in\mathcal{F}_{\Lambda^c}$ for all finite $\Lambda$. (Using the
> conventions $\mu_{\emptyset}^\omega=\delta_\omega$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\emptyset^c}=\mathcal{F}$
> we can in fact allow that $\Gamma$ takes the value $\emptyset$.)
> For a proof
> one simply splits $\Omega$ into the disjoint sets $\{\Gamma=\Lambda\}$ for
> finite $\Lambda$.

.

> $\bullet$
> the **stochastic monotonicity (or FKG order)** of Gibbs
> distributions; writing $\mu\preceq\nu$ when
> $\mu(f)\leq\nu(f)$ for all increasing local (or, equivalently,
> all increasing bounded measurable) real functions $f$ on $\Omega$,
> we have $\mu_{\Lambda}^\omega\preceq\mu_{\Lambda}^{\omega'}$ when $\omega\leq\omega'$, and
> $\mu_{\Lambda}^\omega\preceq\mu_{\Delta}^\omega$ when $\Delta\subset\Lambda$ and $\omega\equiv 
> +1$ on $\Lambda\setminus\Delta$ (the opposite relation holds when $\omega\equiv 
> -1$ on $\Lambda\setminus\Delta$).

Comment: See related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536119/percolation-and-number-of-phases-in-the-2d-ising-model).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume, as in the first part of the proof, that there exists a set $\Gamma$, determined from the outside, such that $\Delta\subset\Gamma\subset\Lambda$. Moreover, by construction, the exterior boundary of $\Gamma$ is entirely composed of $-$ spins (**not** as on your picture! $\Gamma$ is *exactly* the interior of this circuit).

Therefore, by the strong Markov property, we have, on this event,
$$
\mu(\cdot|\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma^c}) = \mu^-_{\Gamma}.
$$
Let $f$ be an increasing local function with support inside $\Delta$. By FKG,
$$
\mu^-_{\Gamma}(f) \leq \mu^-_{\Lambda}(f) \leq \mu_{\Lambda'}^-(f),
$$
for all $\Lambda'\supset\Lambda$. Let $\Lambda'\uparrow\mathbb{Z}^2$ to conclude that
$$
\mu^-_{\Gamma}(f)\leq \mu^-(f).
$$
Let $\mathcal{A}_{\Lambda,\Gamma}$ be the event that there is a $-\star$-circuit inside $\Lambda$, surrounding $\Delta$, and that $\Gamma$ is the interior of the largest such circuit. Let also $\mathcal{A}_\Lambda=\bigcup_\Gamma \mathcal{A}_{\Lambda,\Gamma}$. Then,
$$
\mu(f) \leq \sum_{\substack{\Gamma:\\\Delta\subset\Gamma\subset\Lambda}} \mu( \mu(f | \mathcal{F}_{\Gamma^c}) 1_{\mathcal{A}_{\Lambda,\Gamma}}) + \mu(\mathcal{A}_{\Lambda}^c)
\leq \mu^-(f) + \mu(\mathcal{A}_{\Lambda}^c).
$$
Since $\lim_{\Lambda\uparrow\mathbb{Z}^2}\mu(\mathcal{A}_\Lambda^c) \leq \mu(E^+)=0$, we conclude that
$$
\mu(f) \leq \mu^-(f),
$$
for all increasing local functions $f$. This implies that $\mu\preccurlyeq\mu^-$. But, since $\mu^-$ is stochastically minimal, this means that $\mu=\mu^-$.

Comment: BTW, you might be interested in a book that we are in the process of writing. At the moment, only one chapter has been uploaded, but several are in a rather advanced state and should be made available soon. The drafts of presentable chapters can be found on my homepage (select Book project).

Comment: Thank you very much Velenik. I will access your home page.

Comment: I have noticed that you (again) asked the same question on Math.StackExchange. I think that in such a situation, you should always link both questions, so that readers from one site can access answers given on the other...

Comment: In part $\sum_{\substack{\Gamma:\\\Delta\subset\Gamma\subset\Lambda}} \mu( \mu(f | \mathcal{F}_{\Gamma^c}) 1_{\mathcal{A}_{\Lambda,\Gamma}})$ you used the definition of conditional expectation?

Comment: Yes. And you use the fact that $\Gamma$ is specified from outside, so that $\mathcal{A}_{\Lambda,\Gamma}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma^c}$-measurable.

Comment: Thank you Yvan Velenik! Just one last question. I believe now that I understand well the argument of the proof of this lemma. I can say that most of the lemas and propositions that follows this lema in the article in question depends upon the understanding this proof?

Comment: I am happy that this helped you. Concerning the rest of the paper, I should have a look. I must confess that the last time I read the paper must have been when it came out in 2000 or so. Can't say I remember the details... It is a quite beautiful proof, but the fact that I have now an argument that I find physically much more compelling (though probably less elegant) does not encourage me to read it again ;) . That being said, it is certainly true that if you understand this proof, then the rest should be much easier to read, since the same type of arguments are used again and again.

Comment: @Velenik Dear Velenik, it occurred to me a question some time that resists my efforts to answer it for myself. I was reluctant to ask here but... The question is as follows. Given any $\nu\in\mathcal{G}$ and set $\omega_i=-1\forall i \in\mathbb{Z}^2 $ and $\mu_\Gamma^-(A)$ Gibbs measure in finite volume with boundary condition $-$. Is it true that $ \nu(\cdot|\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma^c})(\omega)=\nu(\cdot|\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma^c})(-)=\mu_\Gamma^-(\cdot)$ This equality seems to me that was used tacitly in resolution up several times. For example the strong Markov property and stochastic monotonicity.

Comment: By Gibbs measure in finite volume I want mean $\mu_{\Gamma}^\omega(A)=\sum_{\omega\in A}\frac{\exp\{\mathcal{H}_\Gamma^{-}(\omega)\}}{\mathcal{Z}_\Gamma^-}$ for all $A\in \{-1,+1\}^\Gamma$ and $\Gamma\subset \mathbb{Z}^2$. Here $\mathcal{H}_\Gamma^{-}(\omega)\}$ is the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Math_overview: yes, this is correct ($\nu$-almost surely, of course). See Chapter 6 of [our book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook), in particular Section 6.3.1.

Comment: @Velenik It is much simpler than I thought. The result is set forth in [equation (6.22)](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/150422_chap_DLR.pdf) of the book (update on April 1). It is a direct consequence of the DLR equations and almost certain uniqueness of conditional probability. I was very excited about the motivations given to set the DLR equations. Especially with the discussion of why the Kolmogorov's extension theorem does not solve the problem of the existence of Gibbs measure.    Thank you very much.

Comment: @Velenik I will dedicate myself the next few weeks to chapter 6 of this book. I was very focused in the chapter on the Ising model. It is a very friendly text to a student. I believe this book will be a great reference in statistical mechanics. More and more I have good surprises with this book. I imagine that in the future will appear in the book, a section or chapter devoted to entropy and variational principles. I look forward to it.

Comment: @Velenik I lack sufficient ability to handle the basic concepts to understand for myself the typical arguments of publications on statistical mechanics and especially on the Ising model. But I think I'll get the maturity that much hope in this area.

Comment: @Math_overview: Thanks for your positive feedback on the book. I am happy you find it useful. There will be a chapter on the variational approach to (translation invariant) Gibbs states at some point, but for the moment, we're working on one chapter on reflection positivity and one on the Pirogov-Sinai theory.